# Sort collection by insertion datetime using only id field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of data and I want to get it sorted by insertion time. I have not any additional fields to store the insert time.  But as I [found out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp) I can get this time from Id.

I have tried this code:

```
return bookmarks.find({}, {sort: {_id.getTimestamp(): 1}, limit: 10});
```

or

```
return bookmarks.find({}, {sort: {ObjectId(_id).getTimestamp(): 1}, limit: 10});
```

but get the error message:

```
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Is there any way to sort collection by insertion datetime using only id field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this isn't possible with Meteor, even if it is with MongoDB. The ObjectID's created with meteor don't bear a timestamp. See http://docs.meteor.com/#collection_object_id

The reason for this is client side code can insert code and it can arrive late on the server, hence there is no guarantee the timestamp portion of the ObjectID will be accurate. In addition to the latency the client side's date is used meaning if they're off it's going to get you incorrect data. I think this is the reason they use an ObjectID but it is completely random.

If you want to sort by date you have to store the time/date separately.

Comment: Perhaps using a server-side collection hook that injects timestamps when documents are created would help here?

Answer (score 1):

The part what i striked out is not accurate. Meteor use it is own id generation which is based on a random string that is while does not apply the doc what i linked before. Check sasha.sochka's comment under.

<strike>It is nearly but not 100% good if you just sort for the _id field . While as it is constructed the first 4 byte is the timestamp in secs (so sorting for the getTimestamps value is not better). Under one second resolution you cannot get the exact order, as it is mentioned in the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#objectid</strike>

It is still true that you can try to check the exact order of the insert/update ops against your collection in the oplog, if you have an oplog, but as it is a capped collection anyway you will see the recent operations only. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/.

Comment: It's not correct about mongodb in meteor. Meteor uses it's own modification of ObjectID in mongo.